# IOS Synchronization Technique

Tags: ios, objective-c

For a class object, I have a need for a locking mechanism that I can use for read and write methods.

I would like to be able permit multiple readers or a single writer. The same lock would apply to all class methods (one lock per object).

At the same time I would like WRITE to have priority over READ. If a writer queues, all new readers should be blocked until the writer gets and releases the lock.

Is there some built-in functionality to implement such a lock?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12765963/642626

Comment: Would `pthread_rwlock` work for your purposes?

Comment: I don't know. It would depend upon whether a write lock would block subsequent read locks; something I was not certain of.

Answer (score 1):

You want "Thread Safety" and "read-write" locks are exactly what you are after.
Look for "read-write lock" on this page of the Apple documentation:
[Synchronisation tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html)

Implementation details are here and will vary depending on what you are doing with your class - see [Using Locks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW16).