# ios/android/windows: multi read global variable but sync write access

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

i have some global var (integer and single), initialised at startup and many threads access them in **read only**. now in very rare case (when the user change the screen orientation of the mobile) i must update all theses globales vars.

On windows i can use a **TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer**, so that thread do *beginread* before to read the variables and the main thread do *beginwrite* before to update the variables. The problem is that TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer not work on ios/android (it's simply a  TCriticalsection on other platform)

so is their any way to block for a moment all the thread activity that i can update peacefully all my global variable ?

i can use AtomicCmpExchange but it's make my code much more heavy to read (i have more than 50 globals variables).

so other option i have it's to not care about simultaneous access when updating the global var, and say later to all thread to reconstruct their internal data, **BUT** for exemple if i have

```
var w, h: single;
w := 100.25
h: 50;
```

and then later i do

```
mainThread: 
h := 75.26

Threadn:
createbitmap(w,h);
```

then the problem is that if threadn read half written value of h, then it's could be anything like 15258425 (as i understand, i not sure) and then i will create a bitmap that will use all the memory :(

any idea what i can do ?

**EDIT / NOTE**

what do you think about this implementation for my TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer that work under android/ios/windows :

```
Var fLock: integer;

procedure TMyMonitor.BeginWrite;
begin
  atomicIncrement(fLock, MaxInt div 2);
  while AtomicCmpExchange(fLock{Target}, 0{NewValue}, 0{Compareand}) <> MaxInt div 2{OriginalOfTarget} do sleep(1);
end;

procedure TMyMonitor.EndWrite;
begin
  atomicDecrement(fLock, MaxInt div 2);
end;

procedure TMyMonitor.BeginRead;
begin
  while atomicIncrement(fLock{Target}) >= Maxint div 2{NewValueOfTarget} do begin
    atomicDecrement(fLock);
    while AtomicCmpExchange(fLock{Target}, 0{NewValue}, 0{Compareand}) >= Maxint div 2{OriginalOfTarget} do sleep(1);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyMonitor.EndRead;
begin
  atomicdecrement(fLock);
end;
```

Comment: Writing this stuff from scratch is anything but simple. Delphi TMonitor - written by EMBT chief architect himself - carried hidden bugs for years. Look at the actual code of Microsoft's implementation of ReaderWriterLockSlim. 50 kb of code, distributed in almost 1500 LOC: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs

Comment: Your problem isn't tearing of individual values but more tearing of the group. So width and height must be written and read atomically. Your proposed lock implementation is currently broken. You don't balance Inc and Dec in BeginRead EndRead. You can readily have simultaneous read and write access. Creating such a lock is really hard. Find a reference implementation to see why. Then use the native platform locks on all platforms.

Comment: On Android that is ReentrantReadWriteLock. On ios read this and do some more research http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765617/re-entrant-read-write-locking-construct. On Windows use slim read write locks.

Comment: yes i know that my implementation is not perfect, but as i say the beginwrite will be very rare and don't need to be very fast ... and i think the beginread is quite good no ? because it's just do atomicincrement ... or i miss something ? i can't read the implementation of aomicincrement because it's an intrinsic delphi function :(